# How to make an UNION in HIVE over two EXTERNAL TABLES which point to the same file

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop-partitioning

I'm trying to write a Hive script which creates two External tables, both of them pointing to the same file LOCATION with differents regular expressions (filters). When I try to make an UNION between them, results aren't as expected. 
The first chunk of code  creates the tables

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE logsFormat1(col1 INT, col2 STRING, col3 INT)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("input.regex" = "Regex1",
"output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s")
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/user/.../directoryFile';

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE logsFormat2(col1 STRING, col2 INT, col3 INT)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("input.regex" = "Regex2",
"output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s")
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/user/.../directoryFile';
```

UNION statement just get results from last SELECT in a weird way.

```
`SELECT l1.url FROM logsFormat1 l1 where l1.url is not null
 UNION ALL
 SELECT l2.url FROM logsFormat2 l2 where l2.url is not null`
```

I discovered that this happen because both TABLES location are pointing to the same file. The problem is that I can't have two files. I need solve this with the same file location due to the real file is very long

Comment: Uh . . . Why not have a single table with all the log records and then use views to select subsets of it in Hive?  It seems like a maintenance nightmare to me to have two tables pointing to the same physical files.

Comment: Because I can't find a correct regular expression which grouped all the different kind of logs formats

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved my problem creating a TEMPORARY TABLE

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TEMPlogsFormat1 
STORED AS TEXTFILE
AS SELECT * FROM logsFormat1 l1
```